# Proper use of quotation marks for executing command using SSH

Tags: bash

I need help with bash quotations rules:

I know I can run such a command:

```
/usr/bin/ssh root@my_srv "ls /usr/local/bin"
```

But I'm lost when I need a more complex commands, like this one that don't works, for example:

```
/usr/bin/ssh root@my_srv "awk '/dbname/{print $NF}' /var/myfile | sed "s/'//g" | sed 's/,//g'"
```

The same command launched directly in the remote server works fine:

```
awk '/dbname/{print $NF}' /var/myfile | sed "s/'//g" | sed 's/,//g'
```

Comment: `ssh root@my_srv bash -s <<'EOF'` will let you put your command *completely unmodified* on the next line, followed by `EOF` when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the inner double quotes with `\` like this:

```
"awk '/dbname/{print \$NF}' /var/myfile | sed \"s/'//g\" | sed 's/,//g'"
```

Answer (score 0):

After SSH login command, script or command may also be written directly without double quotes.